# '\n' saved in array after memset (C)

Tags: c, scanf, memset

I read chars until '\n', convert them to int and sum the numbers until the result is only one digit.

I can't use mod or .

The first run went well, but the second one keep running and not waiting to \n.

any reason for keeping the '\n'?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
char str[8], conv_str[8],c;
int i,val,ans = 0;

while(1){
    printf("Enter 8 values(0-9) :\n");
    scanf("%[^\n]", str);   // Scan values to str untill \n

    for(i = 0;i < 8;i++){
        val = str[i]-48;    //convert from asci to int
        ans += val;
    }

    while(ans > 9){
        // itoa convert int to string, str(the input) is the buffer and 10 is the base
        itoa(ans,conv_str,10);
        ans = (conv_str[0]-48) + (conv_str[1]-48) ;
    }
    printf("the digit is:  %d", ans);

    printf("\ncontinue? (y/n)\n");
    scanf("%s", &c);
    if (c == 'n')
        break;
    memset(str, 0, sizeof(str));
}

return 0;
}
```

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple problems in the code. Some of them are

1. `scanf("%s", &c);` is wrong. `c` is a `char`, you must use `%c` conversion specifier for that.
2. You never checked for the [return value of `scanf()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) calls to ensure success.
3. While scanning for character input, you did not clear the buffer of any existing inputs. Any existing character, including a newline (`'\n'`) already present in the buffer will be considered as a valid input for `%c`. You need to clear the buffer before you read a character input.

Comment: You surely mean "Your code suffers from multiple problems" ;)

Comment: So in addition to memset, adding fflush(stdin)?

Comment: @Karim Hey, I don't have a crystal ball, I can only see what's presented here. :P